# Can gas in a room rotate a fan with asymmetrical spokes?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, collision, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

I was asked this question in an interview. The figure in first part of the question was drawn as shown.
[image: Box full of ideal gas and a rotor.]
The question was to draw the angular position of the point marked on the rim with time. It appears as if the collisions would cause the fan to rotate. But i said that the fan can not have any systematic motion caused by random collisions of the gas.

It appears to me that i have seen this question somewhere, either in some book/any YouTube video/any physics Olympiad/quiz. But i can't find it.

Can y'all good people help me either by discussing the problem, or by pointing me to a reference?

I don't think that any other information was given to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, no such fan could rotate.

If you calculated the torque from each collision, they would all sum up to 0. This because the collisions are happening like pool balls, and angular momentum - which was 0 to start with - is conserved independently with each collision.

A closely related problem - could a fan have a preferred direction to spin - has a different answer, because at high velocities the shape of the object interacting with the fluid has higher order effects (this is where things like drag coefficient, reynolds number, etc. come in to play)

Comment: Is it right to say that the fan can execute a rotational version of the random walk? The angular position of the point on the rim is like the displacement coordinate of a one dimensional random walker?

Comment: @AshutoshShukla yes i think theres some truth to that - but the fluctuations would be so small as to not be visible